# AWS S3 ListObjectsV2 returns "folder" as an object

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-go

I am trying to list all the files in an S3 bucket under a specific directory (I know that S3 does not really have directories.).

The structure is:

`Bucket-Name:Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/file`

So in the S3 world I believe this is just storing a file called the above.

Here is my code:

```
    params := &s3.ListObjectsV2Input{
        Bucket: aws.String(os.Getenv("S3_USER_BUCKET")),
        Prefix: aws.String(key + loc[0] + "/"),
    }

    resp, _ := svc.ListObjectsV2(params)
```

The `resp` contains the file I would expect, as well as the "directory" it is stored in:

```
  Contents: [{
      ETag: "\"TAG\"",
      Key: "Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/",
      LastModified: 2023-03-02 17:32:17 +0000 UTC,
      Size: 0,
      StorageClass: "STANDARD"
    },{
      ETag: "\"TAG\"",
      Key: "Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/file",
      LastModified: 2023-03-02 17:32:30 +0000 UTC,
      Size: 106808,
      StorageClass: "STANDARD"
    }],
  IsTruncated: false,
  KeyCount: 2,
  MaxKeys: 1000,
  Name: "BUCKET",
  Prefix: "Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/"
}
```

I have also tried:

```
    params := &s3.ListObjectsV2Input{
        Bucket: aws.String(os.Getenv("S3_USER_BUCKET")),
        Prefix: aws.String(key + loc[0] + "/"),
        Delimiter: aws.String("/"),
    }

    resp, _ := svc.ListObjectsV2(params)
```

But the result is the same.

Here is the result of params:

```
Params:  {
  Bucket: "BUCKET",
  Prefix: "Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/"
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I assume you are asking why there is a directory returned as an object.

You are quite correct that **Amazon S3 does not use directories**. Instead, the filename (`Key`) of an object is the **full path**, including the name of the file. Directories do not need to be created before an object is created an a particular path.

However, if somebody clicks the **Create folder** button in the S3 management console, it will create a **zero-length object with the name of the directory**. This 'forces' the directory to appear (because there is an object in it), but it is actually a zero-length object.

Looking at your listing result:

```
  Contents: [{
      ETag: "\"TAG\"",
      Key: "Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/",
      LastModified: 2023-03-02 17:32:17 +0000 UTC,
      Size: 0,
      StorageClass: "STANDARD"
```

You will notice it says `Size: 0`, so this is the zero-length object.

If you want to ignore these types of files in your listing, simply skip-over zero-length objects in your code.

Comment: This solution works for most cases, however this logic would also filter out zero-byte files. One could also look at ignoring objects without an extension - however there is not requirement for files to specify an extension either.

The solution I'm going with myself is to filter out any objects that have a key that ends with `${mySearchPrefix}/`. This solution supports the detection of zero-byte files, as well as files without extensions.